# Appium is using CSS selector instead of given ones and it fails

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, mobile, appium

I am trying to write an Automation framework for mobile testing, with Page Object Model. The problem is, that when I'm using @iOSXCUITFindBy or @AndroidFindBy, the program fails with an error that it uses "CSS Selector. My settings, for iOS:

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370)
Appium 2.0.0
xcuitest@4.32.19
uiautomator2@2.29.2

1. POM:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

2. Page Class with locators:

```
public class loginPage {

    public static void initializePageObjects(AppiumDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), loginPage.class);
    }
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(id = "Allow")
    public static WebElement allowButton;
    @iOSXCUITFindBy (iOSClassChain = "**/XCUIElementTypeOther[`label == The App"`]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeImage")
    public static WebElement logo;
    
}
```

3. Main method

```
  MutableCapabilities caps = new MutableCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        caps.setCapability("appium:deviceName", "iPhone 14 Simulator");
        caps.setCapability("appium:deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        caps.setCapability("appium:platformVersion", "16.4");
       caps.setCapability("appium:automationName", "XCUITest");
        caps.setCapability("appium:app","/Users/XXX/Documents/Apps/iOS/XXX.app");
        caps.setCapability("appium:udid","509860CD-4C17-4C62-9523-715AE37C2603");

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723");


        Appium driver = new IOSDriver(url, caps);

        loginPage.initializePageObjects(driver);

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        allowButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(logo.isDisplayed());
```

4. Error:

a) with AppiumFieldDecorator (Main 30 is the "allow.click()")

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

b) if I remove the AppiumFieldDecorator from initElements:

```
Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: ‘4.10.0’, revision: ‘c14d967899’
System info: os.name: ‘Mac OS X’, os.arch: ‘x86_64’, os.version: ‘11.4’, java.version: ‘11.0.13’
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
Command: [fe0e3508-eec0-4511-9ad8-66bcb6f55603, findElement {using=css selector, value=*[name=‘allowButton’]}]
Capabilities {appium:app: /Users/XXX/Docume..., appium:automationName: XCUITest, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:deviceName: iPhone 14 Pro Simulator, appium:deviceOrientation: portrait, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: false, appium:platformVersion: 16.4, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:udid: 509860CD-4C17-4C62-9523-715..., appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: IOS}
Session ID: fe0e3508-eec0-4511-9ad8-66bcb6f55603
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:350)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$PreW3CLocator.findElement(By.java:427)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ByIdOrName.findElement(ByIdOrName.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$1.findElement(ElementLocation.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:350)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.click(Unknown Source)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I wanted to use the mobile locators. It works fine with @FindBy, but I cannot rely on xpath all the time.